# Xcode, objective Class template missing subclass of SKScene

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm working on SpriteKit Project template. If i try to add new Scene going to File -> NewFile and select iOS -> Cocoa Touch -> ObjectiveC Class Template, i can't find the SKScene (nor any other SK framework class) in the drop down list of subclasses.

This is a screenShot of my drop down list:

[image: The drop down list]

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Have you included the `SprikeKit.framework` in your project?

Comment: yes it's a working game but for some reason it won't show SKScene in the subclasses

Comment: Hmm weird.  Are you sure you pre-selecting the right target before doing file > new?

Comment: Same here, did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out. Same thing happened to me. I imported SpriteKit, then tried to make a new class and no SK classes came up. I went ahead and made a class with SKScene typed into the Sublcass of box, and then imported  into it's .h which seemed to import just fine.

Then I did a clean and completely closed and reopened Xcode, and tried to make a new class again, and was able to subclass SK classes just fine. Not sure which step did it, so hopefully you can re-create. Good Luck!

Comment: If you import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h> can you manually create a subclass of SKScene?

Comment: sure but i lose the chance to get the template methods already written, well in most cases you have to override or rewrite the init so no biggie, but still i'm curious why it act like that... i restarted comp, updated the docs of xcode... nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with subclass of SCNScene. I tried adding:

```
import SceneKit
```

to a viewcontroller and it then started to work, not sure if this may help but perhaps worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to make it appear. 
I linked the SprikeKit.framework and SceneKit.framework to my project target, then I oppened an existing viewController.h header file and add the several lines on top :

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>
```

Same answer than R. Shane Davis except I couldn't make it to work with his synthax... don't know why.